# ¿Cómo mostrar texto HTML como texto plano?

Tags: angularjs

En mi formulario tengo un editor de texto en el `textarea`... pero cuando muestro todos los datos que ingrese me los muestra con los formatos como pueden ver en la imagen 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo muestro los datos de la siguiente manera:

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                    <label class="control-label">Introducción:</label> @{{ circular.introduccion || 'Sin introducción'}}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                    <label class="control-label">Recomendaciones:</label> @{{circular.recomendacion || 'Sin recomendaciones' }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                    <label class="control-label ">Reconocimientos:</label> @{{circular.reconocimiento || 'Sin reconocimientos' }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                    <label class="control-label ">Observación:</label> @{{ circular.observacion || 'Sin observación'}}
```

y no quiero que se vean esos textos con las etiquetas de `HTML`, sino como texto plano , ¿ Será que con un filtro de `AngularJs` se puede?

Comment: Puedes ser un poco mas especifica sobre que es lo que buscas?

Comment: ahora si me podrás ayudar? please!

Comment: Necesitas el texto en HTML en algun otro lugar? Por que parece que estas utilizando un editor wysiwyg, si no necesitas que mantenga el formato con el que lo escribes lo mejor seria quitarlo.

Si necesitas el formato en otro parte, entonces hay que limpiar las variables de etiquetas html

Comment: exacto, es lo que quiero, q no aparezcan las etiquetas html pero si el formato que le doy al texto, me entiendes? pero no se como hacerlo, estoy usando textangular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En angular para mostrar la respuesta de tu editor de texto, solo tienes que utilizar `innerHTML` que recibe el string y te lo muestra como HTML.
**lo utilizas de la siguiente forma:**

```
<div [innerHTML]="item.content"></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Si estas usando textangular deberas indicarlo en las etiquetas. Tienes que incluir un

> text-angular

por ejemplo:

```
<div text-angular ng-model="htmlVariable"></div>
```

o

`<text-angular ng-model="htmlVariable"></text-angular>`

Esto hara que el contenido interprete las etiquetas, de lo contrario las veras, acuerdate de inyectar el textangular.